# Show that $\int_{c}{\textbf{r}\cdot d\textbf{r}} = \frac{1}{2}[||\textbf{r}(b)||^2 - ||\textbf{r}(a)||^2] $

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given that $f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2}||\textbf{x}||^2$ what is the $\triangledown{f}$.

This is my solution:

$\frac{1}{2}||\textbf{x}||^2 = \sum^{n}_{k=1}{x{^2}_k} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{x_i}x^2_i) = x_i = \textbf{x}.$

Where $\textbf{x} = <x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n>$.

Is this correct?

Next, I need to show that $\int_{c}{\textbf{r}\cdot d\textbf{r}} = \frac{1}{2}[||\textbf{r}(b)||^2 - ||\textbf{r}(a)||^2] $.

So far I have done the following but haven't got anywhere:

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Line integrals.

LHS:
$\int_{c}{<x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n>\cdot <r'_{1}(t),r'_{2}(t),\cdots,r'_{n}(t)>} dt = [\frac{1}{2}<x^2_1,x^2_2,\cdots,x^2_n> \cdot <r_1(t),\cdots,r_n(t)>]|^{a}_{b}=
\frac{1}{2}[||\textbf{x}||^2 \cdot <r_1(t),\cdots,r_n(t)>]|^{a}_{b}$

After this, I have no clue how to continue.If someone can show me a valid proof that would be nice, or just give me some hints so I can clearly continue with my proof.

Thank You.

Comment: No, your start is not correct: You state that a number ($\frac 1 2 \|x\|^2$) is equal to a vector (**x**). Pay attention to what type each object is throughout, and that will fix most of the issues with the attempted proof.

Comment: So you are saying that x is now a constant?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the expression $$\frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2 = x$$ cannot ever be correct because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you explain why.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, one of those two is a number and one is a vector. A number and a vector cannot be equal because they are fundamentally different objects.

Comment: To elaborate on T.Bongers' statement, in the line he is referring to the partial derivative operator appears out of nowhere. What would be correct is $\nabla \frac12 \| x \|^2 = x$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the fundamental theorem of line integrals, if $\vec{F}\left(\vec{r}\right)=\nabla \phi(\vec{r})$, then we can evaluate the line integral of $\vec{F}$ on a curve, which starts at $a$ and ends at $b$, by evaluating the difference in the potential $\phi$ at the end point and the starting point.

$$ \int_C \vec{F}(\vec{r})\cdot \mathrm d \vec{r} = \phi(b)-\phi(a). $$

In your problem you have $F(\vec{r})=\vec{r}$ and $\phi(r)=\frac12 \|\vec{r} \|^2$. The statement you are trying to prove pretty much follows immediately from these observations and the theorem itself.

Answer (score 0):

By definition
\begin{align*}
  \left \| \mathbf{r}(t) \right \|^{2} &=
  \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}(t) \\
  \frac{d}{dt} \left \| \mathbf{r}(t) \right \|^{2} &=
  \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t)+\mathbf{r}'(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}(t) \\
  & = 2\, \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \\
  \left \| \mathbf{r}(t) \right \|^{2}+C' &=
  \int 2\, \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \, dt \\
  \int \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \, dt &=
  \frac{1}{2} \left \| \mathbf{r}(t) \right \|^{2}+C
\end{align*}