# Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals Semi Proof

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

Here's a question I'm working on that I have little understanding of. I'm new to line integrals and vector fields, but here it goes:

Suppose $C$ is a continuous differential curve, and $r(t)$, $a\leq t \leq b$ is a vector function, show 
$\int_{c}r\bullet dr = \frac{1}{2}[||r(b)||^2-||r(a)||^2]$

And as a hint I'm being told that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||x||^2$ should be used to find $\nabla f$, and that the fundamental theorem of line integrals should be used.

Since I'm new to this, where I'm stuck is finding out $\nabla f$. Is it just $<||x||>$ ? I don't see how this can be used to show the statement above.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: This question was asked yesterday, by someone who was using multiple accounts to post related questions. Was that also you?

Comment: No, I searched around for a question similar to this and couldn't find it here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674044/show-that-int-c-textbfr-cdot-d-textbfr-frac12-textbfrb/1674083#1674083

Comment: $\nabla f = \vec{r}$ in this case to answer your question.

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: This link also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674064/how-to-compute-f-textbfx-frac12-textbfx2#comment3415450_1674064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,

$$ \frac12 \| \vec{r} \|^2 = \frac12 ( x^2+y^2+z^2), $$

so that,

$$ \nabla \frac12 \| \vec{r} \|^2 = \frac12 < 2x, 2y, 2z> = <x,y,z> = \vec{r}.$$

Where each component of $\nabla \frac12 \| \vec{r} \|^2$ is computed with the appropriate partial derivative operation.